# Conditional Inherit font, size and color

Tags: css

I'm having problems making a style that inherits color and size when link is inside of h1 and span tags. They should behave at same way if they were inside td's. I've put the desired output in the link names.

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/lasseedsvik/ym7M7/9/

**Style**

```
* {
    color: #000;    
    font-family: Times;
    font-size: 14px;
}

a {
    color: red;
}

h1
{
    font-family: arial, helvetica;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: green;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
    Default text color
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="#">Red link . default font</a>
    <br />
    <h1><a href="#">Green link - Arial 27px</a></h1>
    <br />
    <span style="font-size: 18px"><a href="#">Red link - 18px default font</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `h1 a { font-size: inherit; color: inherit; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
h1 a, span a{
    font-size:inherit;
    font-family:inherit;
    color:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `inherit` keyword:

```
h1 a, 
span a {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
}
```

[Demo up here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/7LPm6/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inherit` keyword to request for inheritance, but it’s not supported by IE 7. You get better browser coverage by explicitly declaring what you want, e.g.

```
h1, h1 a
{
    font-family: arial, helvetica;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: green;
}
```

to set properties on both the direct content of `h1` and any `a` element contained in `h1`.